# PowerBI using AD

Tags: azure-sql-database, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am trying connect to Azure SQL database with PowerBI using AD Authentication. Basically we want users of the PowerBI report to use their own AD credentials when they connect to the database.

Using windows authentication I can connect to the Azure SQL via SSMS. But when I try the exact same way via PowerBI its says "user was not authorized"
[image: PowerBI Login]

I have on Azure SQL Server created a AD user (FROM EXTERNAL) that is my AD User.
[image: SSMS]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure firewall rules for the SQL Azure database are configured to "Allow access to Azure services".

Currently Power BI doesn’t support AAD authentication when connecting to Azure SQL Database, but using Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 it is possible to do it as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/04/06/connect-from-power-bi-to-azure-sql-database-using-aad-authentication/).

```
ODBC (for AD PW Auth; must have ODBC Drive 13 for SQL Server) 
Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=<servernamehere>;Database=<databasenamehere>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword
```

Comment: Can I publish to PowerBI online (app.powerbi.com) using an ODBC connection?

Comment: As far as I understand the options are Azure SQL (without AAD authentication) and SSAS Tabular Models (via GateWay).

Comment: Yes you need the gateway to keep the data updated. Another Power BI user received the same article I posted as answer and he is trying to run on power BI online also. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/Can-t-connect-to-Azure-SQL-Database/m-p/243888#M12653